# Как изменить href?

Tags: php, html, href

У меня есть новостной сайт. На главной странице есть список новостей. При переходе на новость, отображается текст новости и теги. 
К примеру, новость отображается по ссылке `http://localhost/diploma/sports/?id=1`
При переходе по тегу, к примеру по тегу sports, отображаются все новости с этим тегом. 
Проблема в том, что именно эти новости по тегу, имеют ссылку вида

```
http://localhost/diploma/sports/sports/?id=1
```

Но должны быть вида:

```
http://localhost/diploma/sports/?id=1
```

Сервер автоматически подставляет в href `http://localhost/diploma/sports` , а затем добавляет /sports/?id=1

Вариант добавить в href  "../" не помогает, поскольку тогда новости на главной странице получают ссылку вида  `http://localhost/diploma/?id=1`  (без sports)

Есть ли возможность сменить ссылку по-другому? Генерируется она так:

```
<a href="<?php echo $news->news_category .'/?id='. $news->id ?>"
```

`$news` присылает одно и тоже.

Comment: Что покажет если вывести переменную  $news вывести  через var_dump  ?

Comment: @Даниил 
object(News)#10 (8) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "5"

  ["img"]=>
  string(20) "includes/img/ava.jpg"

  ["news_title"]=>
  string(15) "новость4"

  ["text"]=>
  string(89) "Равным 3552образом ра235мки и место обучения кадров"
  ["news_category"]=>
  string(6) "sports"

  ["tags"]=>
  string(8) "football"
  ["date"]=>
  string(10) "2017-11-04"

  ["total_read"]=>
  string(0) ""
}

Comment: <a href="/<?php echo $news->news_category .'/?id='. $news->id ?>" так попробуйте

Comment: @Даниил теперь на главной новости имеют ссылку вида http://localhost/sports/?id=1  (без /diploma/)  Надо попробовать на сервер залить, там может работать, т.к. сайт не будет лежать дополнительно внутри папки. Хотя до конца и не ясно почему такая проблема

Comment: Работайте на localhost через virtualhost